# Missing Makefiles during installation of tesseract 4 on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, ocr, tesseract

I am trying to install tesseract 4 on ubuntu 16.04 by building it from source. I installed all required packages in addition to Leptonica Library (1.74). 
However, when i try to run ./autogen.sh from my Tesseract decompressed folder I keep getting the following errors:

```
Makefile.am:19: error: required directory ./viewer does not exist
Makefile.am:19: error: required directory ./wordrec does not exist
Makefile.am:19: error: required directory ./training does not exist
Something went wrong, bailing out !
```

Answer (score 0):

The required folders were not downloaded during uncompression (tar command). I fixed the problem by cloning instead.